# Atata. C#. How to open new tab?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, atata

How to open a new tab in the Chrome browser?

- I can open at the beginning of a test:

  ```
            AtataContext.Configure()
                .UseChrome()
                .WithArguments("new tab")
  ```
- I tried to press the shortcuts "CTRL + T:

```
    [PressKeys("control" + "t", TriggerEvents.AfterClick)]
```

OR

```
.Press("^t");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update for Atata v2.2+**

New methods were added in Atata v2.2.0 to `Go` class:

- `Go.ToNewWindow<TPage>(...)`
- `Go.ToNewWindowAsTab<TPage>(...)`

**Solution for older Atata version**

Apparently CTRL+T combination doesn't work anymore for chromedriver. But we can use `window.open()` JavaScript which also opens new tab.

```
AtataContext.Current.Driver.ExecuteScript("window.open()");

// You also need to switch to newly opened tab.
Go.ToNextWindow<OrdinaryPage>(); // Set the type of your page object instead of OrdinaryPage.
Go.ToUrl("/someurl"); // Set URL.
```

You can also extract this code block to a method:

```
public static TPage CreateAndSwitchToNewTab<TPage>(string url)
    where TPage : Page<TPage>
{
    AtataContext.Current.Driver.ExecuteScript("window.open()");

    var page = Go.ToNextWindow<TPage>();
    Go.ToUrl(url);

    return page;
}
```

And use it in tests in a form of:

```
CreateAndSwitchToNewTab<ProductsPage>("/products")
    .PageTitle.Should.Contain("Products");
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Yevge I get Iwebdriver doesn't contain a definition for ExecuteScript

Comment: Right @RohitKumar. For Atata v2 the `AtataContext.Current.Driver.ExecuteScript("window.open()");` line should be replaced with `AtataContext.Current.Driver.AsScriptExecutor().ExecuteScript("window.open()");`.